# how to set bundler version with rvm?

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler, gemset

I  have a project that uses RVM, and it have .ruby-gemset and .ruby-version files, but I want set the bundler vession too. I tried .ruby-bundler but not worked.
When enter in the folder this set the gemset and ruby version correctly but not install de bundler version correctly, the effect is that in my project each machine is with a specific version of bundler, and each commit change the Gemfile.lock, there is a easy way to force everyone use the same bundler verion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit last 2 lines of the Gemfile.lock in your project:

```
BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.0
```

change `2.2.0` with the version you want.
Then run `bundle install`, the bundler should inform you about the bundler version problem. And bundler will provide you some instructions about how to upgrade the bundler.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the bundler version in the Gemfile, and bundler will use the correct version.